# How to create two dimensional list of characters from file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need some simple help. I have file with content like this:

```
jdss
sdjk
nbjs
```

So there is unknown numbers of lines and unknown numbers of characters in every line but all of lines is the same length. I want to get a two dimensional list

```
[['j','d','s','s'],
['s','d','j','k'],
['n','b','j','s']]
```

how to do it in the simplest way? What I tried:

```
list = [[]]
for line in f:
    whichLine = 0
    for ch in line:
        list [whichLine].append(ch)
    list.append([])
    whichLine += 1
```

But it doesn't work like I want.

Comment: FYI, the fix you need for your code is `list[-1].append(ch)` instead of `list [whichLine].append(ch)` Then it works as you expect, except it leaves an extra empty list at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> [list(line) for line in f]
[['j', 'd', 's', 's'], ['s', 'd', 'j', 'k'], ['n', 'b', 'j', 's']]
```

Comment: Ok, I think it is simplest way. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

list comprehension works well here.

```
my_list = [[c for c in line] for line in f]
```

(note its usually not a good idea to overwrite the name `list`)

if you don't want the newline characters

```
my_list = [[c for c in line.strip()] for line in f]
```

Comment: As @Stefan mentioned, `list(line)` or `list(line.strip())` is sufficient to convert a string into a list :)

Answer (score 1):

```
data = []
filename = '/path/to/file'
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        data.append(list(line))
```

Answer (score 1):

To demonstrate how close your code was to being correct, this is a fixed solution using your method:

```
my_list = []
for line in f:
    my_list.append([])
    for ch in line:
        my_list[-1].append(ch)
```

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz `[-1]` gives you the last element in the list. it's very handy.